# How to unset, calculate and updateOne data in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 documents in MongoDB, I want to remove the object "scoreDetailLog.ITD.XuanNT" and then recalculate the total score, and assign it to the "total" variable.
Can do that in updateOne Mongodb?
Thanks!

```
{
    "id": "111",
    "total": 725,
    "scoreDetailLog": {
        "ITD": {
          "NVLoi": {
              "score": 205
          },

          "HaoPPD": {
              "score": 240
          },
          "XuanNT": {
              "score": 280
          }
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "222",
    "total": 600,
    "scoreDetailLog": {
        "ABC": {
          "Name1": {
              "score": 100
          },

          "Name2": {
              "score": 200
          },
          "Name3": {
              "score": 300
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

I run and get error this.scoreDetailLog is undefined,I'm a newbie!

```
let resultData = await ldbDataModel.updateOne(
    { id: 111 }, 
    {
        $unset: { scoreDetailLog.ITD.XuanNT: ''},
        $set: {
        total: function () {
            var total = 0;
            var entityScoreDetail = this.scoreDetailLog.ITD;
            for (var user in entityScoreDetail) {
                total += entityScoreDetail[user].score;
            }
            
            return total;
            }()
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Using dynamic values as field names and having a dynamic level of nesting are considered anti-patterns and introduce unnecessary complexity to querying. Consider refactoring your schema.

Comment: Another data model might look something like `{"id": "111", "total": 725, "league": "ITD", "scoreDetailLog": [{"name": "NVLoi", "score": 205}, {"name": "HaoPPD", "score": 240}, {"name": "XuanNT", "score": 280}]}`.